# GRUB locked bios help please

Tags: grub2

When installing Linux, everything went fine until I restarted to go back to windows. GNU GRUB came up and didn’t let me boot to windows. I tried resetting the computer and going to the bios to change boot order. But when I do that everything is locked up and I can’t change anything in it. The only way to get to windows is by going through Linux bootloader first.

How do I remove Linux, GRUB and everything from that so I can boot to windows and access my BIOS again.

MOBO: ASUS Z73e (I think)